# Set text with special characters

Tags: c#, wpf, string, character

I need to display special characters in TextBlock from string in code.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tboxData" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="&gt;&gt; &lt;&lt;" />
```

is working, but I need to do it from c#:

```
tboxData.Text = "&gt;&gt; &lt;&lt;";
```

And this doesn't print **>> <<** in TextBlock.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you might need to use encoded characters for some reason (perhaps you're not using literals and are reading in an xml file or something):

```
tboxData.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&gt;&gt; &lt;&lt;")
```

Note that you'll have to add a reference to the `System.Web` assembly.

Comment: +1 for use case, but if you're targeting .NET 4 (client or full), you can use [System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx) instead to avoid having to reference the `System.Web` assembly if you don't need `System.Web` for anything else.

Comment: Thanks! I'm targeting .NET 4. System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode is working great. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't this just work?

```
tboxData.Text = ">><<";
```

The reason the XAML requires you to use the encoding is because XAML parses the `<` and `>` characters, so you need to ensure that the parser knows that you want to display the `<>` characters and not parse them as tokens.

Comment: This is not possible, because I'm receiving string from web service and it already contains those characters.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
tboxData.Text = ">><<";
```

You don't have to worry about HTML entities when writing a string in C#. It has to be done in XAML because those characters represent opening and closing tags of your code.

Comment: Large string (not only those four characters) is being received from web service, so I can't set text manually. It was only for better visualization. I used System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode from another answer and it helped. Thanks.